# connect to server from command line

Tags: server, command-line, ftp

In ubuntu 12.04 there is a connect to server in the global file menu. I use this to connect  to my websites ftp server. Is there a command to do this from the terminal?

Comment: How about `ftp`?

Comment: I tried ftp but I would like a one line function that mounts the folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about gvfs-mount, if you like the way nautilus handles things:

```
gvfs-mount 'ftp://youruser@yourserver.com/path/'
```

You will find the respective path mounted in `$HOME/.gvfs/`.

For more information use

```
gvfs-mount --help
```

as there is no man page. `dpkg -L gvfs-bin` will give you all the gvfs-tools that you can use from commandline. And also [Google](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=ubuntu%20mount%20ftp%20location) [is](http://blog.damontimm.com/how-to-mount-a-sftp-folder-ssh-ftp-on-ubuntu-linux-using-sshfs-fuse/) [your](http://ubuntu-install.blogspot.co.at/2009/05/ftp-site-in-fstab.html) [friend](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=ubuntu%20mount%20ftp%20location&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CFkQFjAB&url=http://hartvig.de/2009/howto-mount-a-ftp-drive-in-ubuntu/&ei=3XUdUIyGDuel4gTNs4CoAw&usg=AFQjCNFHqpvTzUN1F6KGoomTkBnm9EA3Hg&cad=rja).

Comment: In more modern releases of Ubuntu, you'll find the path mounted at `/run/user/uid/gvfs/`, where `uid` is your user id number, an integer usually 1000 or a little over 1000.

Answer (score 0):

Why not filezilla you just enter your info and it saves it for any other time needing to login plus it is easy to work.

Comment: I am creating a program for myself that i can use to automate things i do daily. I can access ftp do upload and everything, but i want to mount it